# Azure : Load Balance multiple instance of application from different VM's

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-application-gateway

I have three instance of an application in vm1 and another 3 in vm2. Each application has different context path and the URL's are below
VM1
https://hostname/random1
https://hostname/random2
https://hostname/random3
VM2
https://hostname/random1
https://hostname/random2
https://hostname/random3

Is it possible to load balance them  and use https://hostname/random as an external URL to reach the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Azure Application Gateway**.

configure Application Gateway routing rules so that requests to https://hostname/random are distributed across the six instances of your application on VM1 and VM2

Also, you can use Path-Based Routing rules to define your specific paths `/random1`, `/random2`, `/random3`) in the load balancer and route them to `/random`.

Dont forget to configure the health probes to check the health of each application instance

for more information, please check [Azure Application GW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/quick-create-portal)

Another solution by using a reverse proxy like Nginx to route incoming requests to your application and load balance the traffic between instances